# searching for the highest and the smallest value in a specific range - Random

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, loops, random

so far in the program the values were searched randomly, but I want to modify the program to search for random numbers in a given range. Generally speaking, My point is that the draw should be from the given range (from-to), and not up to 1000 random numbers as in the above code, so my question is:

*How can I pass the value from and to random: rand.nextInt (?) so that the numbers are randomly drawn in a given range. so I generally need to get a printout from the program like in the question: expected output*

```
// Create array to be searched
final int[] arrayToSearch = new int[20];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSearch.length; i++)
        arrayToSearch[i] = rnd.nextInt(1000);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayToSearch));

final int PARTITIONS = 4;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[PARTITIONS];
final int[] partitionMin = new int[PARTITIONS];
final int[] partitionMax = new int[PARTITIONS];
        for (int i = 0; i < PARTITIONS; i++) {
final int partition = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
        // Find min/max values in sub-array
        int from = arrayToSearch.length * partition / PARTITIONS;
        int to = arrayToSearch.length * (partition + 1) / PARTITIONS;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int j = from; j < to; j++) {
        min = Math.min(min, arrayToSearch[j]);
        max = Math.max(max, arrayToSearch[j]);
        }
        partitionMin[partition] = min;
        partitionMax[partition] = max;

        });
```

so far:

```
partition 0: from=0, to=5, min=23, max=662 //the draw in the range 0-5, draw is outside the specified range
```

expected output:

```
partition 1: from=0, to=5, min=1, max=3 // the draw takes place within the given range 0 to 5
partition 2: from=20, to=30, min=22, max=29 //the draw takes place within the given range 20 to 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass the value from and to random: rand.nextInt (?) so that the numbers are randomly drawn in a given range

Try it like this. This will generate values between `from` and `to` inclusive.

```
int from = -100;
int to = 100;

int draw = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(from, to);
```

You can actually generate your own `Supplier` to just get random numbers in a specified range.

The `BiFunction` returns a `Supplier`.  And the `Supplier` can be called
 to get the a random number in the range.

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, IntSupplier> rndGen = (f,
        t) -> () -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(f, t+1);
                
IntSupplier rnd = rndGen.apply(from,to);
```

So each time `rnd.getAsInt()` is invoked,  you will get a number in the desired range.

Note: There are of course methods that do this pretty much automatically.  But I presumed you wanted to work out the logic of finding min and max yourself so I did not include those.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Random` has method [ints (long streamSize, int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) to generate `IntStream` of random numbers in the given range, and then the summary statistics may be collected for such stream:

```java
static void printMinMax(int size, int from, int to) {
    IntSummaryStatistics stats = new Random()
            .ints(size, from, to)
            .summaryStatistics();
    System.out.printf("min = %d, max = %d%n", stats.getMin(), stats.getMax());
}
```

Test:

```
printMinMax(20, 20, 200); // min = 30, max = 198
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a random number of your choosing however you want.
2. If it's under your `From` value, add your `From` value to it.
3. If it's over your `To` value mod it by your `To` value.